# Mysql Select multiple columns and group by single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql where i need to display the columns `Uid`, `CreatedDate` and `Action_key` and `Value`, grouping by `action key`.

Table: **UsersOptStatus**

[image]

**Expected result:**

I need to order by desc CreatedDate and show the latest Action_keys

[image]

*Below is what i tried* - This gives me all the Action_keys, but i need to show latest Action_keys based on last (ie Desc) Created_date:

```
SELECT uid,
       action_key,
       value,
       Max(createddate) CreatedDate
FROM   usersoptstatus
WHERE  uid = 1607
GROUP  BY action_key,
          value;
```

**[image: Output:]**

Even the below query **not gives me** `Expected Result`,

```
SELECT uid,
       value,
       action_key
FROM   (SELECT uid,
               Max(createddate) CreatedDate
        FROM   usersoptstatus
        GROUP  BY uid) A
       INNER JOIN usersoptstatus USING (uid, createddate)
WHERE  uid = 1607
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: No images pls. Always copy the tables as formatted code text.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? 8.0 introduces window functions, which would allow for a simpler, arguably easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Derived table, you are doing `Group By` on `uid`. Instead, you need to `Group By` on `action_key` to get the maximum value of `createddate` for every `action_key`.

Now, you can join this result-set to the main table on `action_key` and `createddate`.

Also, I prefer `ON` clause based joining instead of either `Using` or old-school comma based implicit Joins.

```
SELECT uos.uid,
       uos.value,
       uos.action_key
FROM   (SELECT action_key,
               Max(createddate) AS maxcreateddate
        FROM   usersoptstatus 
        WHERE uid = 1607 
        GROUP  BY action_key) A
INNER JOIN usersoptstatus AS uos
  ON uos.action_key = A.action_key AND 
     uos.createddate = A.maxcreateddate
WHERE  uos.uid = 1607
ORDER  BY uos.id DESC;
```

Comment: @Sushivam are you using MySQL version 8.0+ ?

Comment: No this is 5.6!

Comment: hi @Madhur Bhaiya, bro , wanted to know like, if i select * from usersoptstatus, if the Action_key is loggedin and value = 0 (for some time xx) and again if i do the entry action_key = loggedin and value =0 (at time xy), i should not store that entry if do select * from table..how can i achieve this

Comment: @Sushivam it is hard to understand what you are asking with just words. Seeing sample table data and expected output helps instead. Please try to put a question. This time don't use images. Please check this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: Have updated my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313411/mysql-check-for-last-entry-in-table-while-inserting