# Mysql check for last entry in table while inserting

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I have a table which has 2 columns `Action_key` (which stores `loggedin` and `optin` values) and `Value` (which stores 0 or 1)

My table has `Id` column  auto increment.

**Update**

Below is how im inserting by checking the condition.

Now i need the condition to check if the newly inserting row has same value as the last record's `Uid`, `Action_key` and `Value`, else it should insert.

```
 $uniquedataoptininArray = array(   //except CreatedDate
        'Uid'=> $uid,
        'Action_key'=> $actionkey,
        'Value'=>$login_optin_value
        );
$userexists=  $this->getUserOptInLogTable()->getOptinLogindetails($uniquedataoptininArray);

if($userexists){

         echo 'record exist';

     }else{
          echo 'To be inserted';
          $result =  $this->getUserOptInLogTable()->insertdetails($dataArray);
```

The below query gives me the last inserted row - Which is fine. but need to know how i can check the condition using rhe below query

```
$qry ="SELECT * FROM UserOptInLog WHERE Uid = ". $uid ." ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

Current problem.

**Conditions when it should insert**

1) If my below table is filled with values like shown, now im trying to insert a row with `Uid 1608`, `ActionKey loggedin` and `Value 1`, but it is not inserting.

2) Or if i make an entry with values `Uid 1608`, `Action_key optin` and `value 1` - it is not inserting (which should insert ideally)

**Conditions when it should not insert**

1) with the tables existing data- if i insert `Uid 1608`, `ActionKey loggedin` and `value 0` - basically the same row as last row - it should not insert

[image]

Comment: Adding an Id column would help you achieve that,you will only need to select the last Id then check the values

Comment: also if you want to add an id column make sure to use autoincrement feature

Comment: Have updated the question, i have id column with autoincrement

Comment: You will need to fire a select query first to check if last value of logged in is 0. and then update accordingly. please provide the sample table structure with data in tabular format

Comment: Have updated my question @MadhurBhaiya, let me know if the question is clear

Answer (score 1):

If you already have **last id** from `$this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue()` and **Action_key** & **value** as `"logged_in"` & `0` respectively, then there is no need to be concerned about your query...

1. Just check for a record where these 3 items (columns) match:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `table` 
   WHERE `id` = <last_id>    # one you get from $this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue()
   AND `Action_key` = 'loged_in'
   AND `value` = 0
   ```
2. Check for the number of records returned from above query:

   - if it returns null, `INSERT` your new record
   - else, Just Ignore

---

**UPDATE**

1. Just check for **the Uid** where these 3 items (columns) match:

   ```
   SELECT Uid FROM `table`   # get just Uid column
   WHERE `id` = <last_id>    # one you get from $this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue()
   AND `Action_key` = 'loged_in'
   AND `value` = 0
   ```
2. Match the Uid returned from above query:

   - if it **doesn't** match the new Uid (the record that is going to be inserted), `INSERT` your new record
   - else, Just Ignore

---

**ALSO**

You can check for the last value for Uid:

```
SELECT Action_key, value FROM table
WHERE Uid = uid 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

this will return the last item for the target Uid. Then you can match the `Action_key` and `value` columns for matching records...

Comment: Id is autoincrement , UId is same and loggedin and 0 can be same

Comment: I am checking if last UId and Action_key and Value- if all 3 are same (in the last entry) then it should not make a new entry in table

Comment: The problem is my query is in controller and $this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue() is done in Model file.. so cant use the above query

Comment: Sorry for mis-understanding, but can you tell me what values **do you have** when inserting a new record???

Comment: Initially if table is empty, it will insert...but for one user ,if the last id is loggedin 0 , next entry should not be there..if last entry is loggedin 1 , then next time it can insert loggedin 0 again...basically previous data and new entry for that user(UID) should not be same...hope i m clear

Comment: Have updated my condition of inserting, can you suggest on that..right now all values are inserting...ie) loggedin 0 entry even if it exists

Comment: Have updated the question with your part of the answer (Under ALSO) part, but i am still not able to insert as expected, hope the question updated is clear now..let me know @Talha

Answer (score 0):

You may use such a statement with subquery

```
insert into tab
select q.* 
  from  
  (
  select *
    from tab
   where date_ = ( select max(date_) from tab where Action_key = 'loggedin' )
     and Value = 0
  ) q   
where date_ is not null;
```

Comment: if you need an answer if the insert happened in your application look at the rows affected which is hopefully exposed via Zend.